# Mongodb: Multi _id aggregate group not using index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I have some indexes on my collection that look like this:

```
   (u'cdr3_len',1.0),
   (u'v_gene.fam', 1.0),
   (u'v_gene.gene', 1.0),
   (u'd_gene.fam', 1.0),
   (u'd_gene.gene', 1.0),
   (u'j_gene.gene', 1.0),
   (u'isotype', 1.0)
```

When I do something like a simple query -

```
db.coll.find({'cdr3_len':20,'v_gene.fam':'IGHV3',
          'd_gene.fam':'IGHD3',
          'j_gene.full':'IGHJ6*03'},
          limit=100).explain()['queryPlanner']['winningPlan']
```

It tells me I'm using an IXSCAN. However, when I do a multi _id group in the aggregation pipeline:

```
pipeline = [{$group:
                {_id:{'cdr3_len':$cdr3_len,
                       'v_gene.fam':$v_gene.fam,
                       'd_gene.gene':$d_gene.gene,
                       'j_gene.full':$j_gene.full},
                 "count":{$sum:1}}}]
```

and run explain, it  tells me I'm doing a full COLLSCAN. I'm not following why the query by find uses the index, and why the aggregation pipeline is doing a COLLSCAN. Is there something intrinsic about a multi-id group statement where you have to use a COLLSCAN?

Thanks

Comment: The only aggregation pipeline stages that **can** ever you an index are `$match` and `$geoNear`, and then **only ever** as the very first stage of the aggregation pipeline before any content in the original collection is altered. The other operations and stages are not "queries" and therefore never accesss an index. Subsequent `$match` stages which are the only "query", cannot use an index since the documents remaining to be processed are no longer part of the original collection.

Comment: I think you missed [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-operator-and-performance)

Comment: @BatScream `$sort` as an aggregation pipeline stage **does not** use an index. Possibly with the exception of immediately following a `$match` stage ( have not checked this in 3.2, but not in earlier versions ) would it make any sense to presume an index could be used anyway.

Comment: @BlakesSeven - it does and has been doing so since it was introduced. It makes perfect sense and has use cases.